# Why is the filtering through WEBURL not working

Tags: angular

PROBLEM:

I am searching for a string `adhoc` from the the webURL  as `http://localhost:4200/submission-eye/adhoc`and I don't see any data (screnshot#1)displayed,only after I hit an enter in the text area`Filter All Submission Data`I can see data (screenshot#2)

I see this problem only happens for strings in the column `Rootbuild`,all other string search for other columns(Submission Date,Train,Project Tags,Radars,SDK) seems to work fine when searching in webURL

I created a stackblitz for my problem @https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcwrpe?file=src%2Findex.html ,can anyone provide guidance on what could be the issue here?
[image]

After hitting enter:

[image]

Sample response:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d684ec37e752b1279e2ce8f"),
    "radars" : [ 
        "54098605", 
        "54725536", 
        "54730610"
    ],
    "root_build" : [ 
        {
            "wisedash_url" : "https://wisedash.company.com/tools/jump2root.php?root_id=10724",
            "root_name" : "mac-wlan-08282019a"
        }
    ],
    "train" : "macOStrain",
    "inserted_by" : "ibait",
    "inserted_on" : ISODate("2019-08-29T15:16:35.686Z"),
    "project_tag_list" : [ 
        "CoreCapture-423", 
        "AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1429", 
        "companyBCMWLANV3-438"
    ],
    "SDK" : [ 
        "NewestmacOStrain"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide a dummy json sample of response

Comment: @SiddharthaGupta - I updated my question with a sample response

Comment: I've create a stackblitz(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvttek) with the response you have provided and it seems to be working fine... I'm I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `filterPredicate` does not trigger a re-filter.  Changing the `filter` does.  You change the `filter` first and it filters using the default predicate.  This is good enough for most of the fields, but not for the `Rootbuild` field.  Then you change the `filterPredicate` but it doesn't trigger a re-filter.  Later, if you do anything that triggers a re-filter it works correctly.

If you set the `filter` after you set the `filterPredicate` it will work.  Updated StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfrjlt?file=src/app/latest-submitted-project-page/latest-submitted-project-page.component.ts